# UIWebView inside UIScrollView and scrolling to the selected field in the web view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I have got a `UIWebView`, surrounded by the other elements, inside my `UIScrollView`. When any html field on the webView is selected it is not scrolled to it because scrolling of webView is disabled. 
How can i scroll main UIScrollView to that field?

Answer (score 0):

scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
Also, making sure if your scrollview set to cliptobounds = NO;
also, bring the webview to front if needed, maybe the scrollview is in clearcolor and stays in the back of the webview or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help me, but i think you don't understand me... Scrolling of the web view should't be turned on, but one of the top scroll view should be. So when the field of web view selected should scroll not web view, but top scrollView. May be it's a little difficult to understand, sorry.

Comment: set the ClipToBounds = NO. Also, set the content of scrollView.contentSize = anysize and set to scrollEnabled = YES. Hopefully, it helps